# Making a class or struct to be friend of all template instantiated class?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct s1;

template <typename... type>
class Base : public type::inner...
{
    friend struct s1;

};

struct Test;

struct s1
{
    template <typename... type>
    friend class Base;

    friend class Test;

    private:
    struct inner {

    int member1;
    int member2;
    };
};

struct s2
{
    struct inner {

    int member3;
    int member4;
    };
};

struct Test : public s1::inner, public s2::inner
{

};

int main()
{
    Base<s1, s2> base;
    base.member1 = 0;

    Test t;
    t.member3 = 22;

    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I tried to compile the above code I am getting the below error

In instantiation of 'class Base':
error: 'struct s1::inner' is private

However the class Test is compiled successfully without error when tried to compile this program by commenting out the base variable. I want to make the template class named Base to be friend of struct s1. How do I do that?

Comment: i notice that you are declaring class Test and friending class test, but Test is a struct. Is this intentional?

Comment: _"However the class Test is compiled successfully without error."_ What do you mean? I'd suspect the compiler stops befor statring to complain about `Test`.

Comment: @tramstheman Its a typo. Sorry. πάντα ῥεῖ I tried compiling the test by commenting out base variable. This way it is successfully compiled. Will update the question

Comment: g++ chokes, clang++ swallows.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `template <typename... type> friend class Base<type>;` ?

Comment: I just ran your code as posted and it compiles and runs fine. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @tramstheman TDM Gcc 64 bit in windows 10.

Comment: @n.m. Is clang correct or g++ correct? Any explanations please...

Comment: can you edit the question to include the your console logs?

Comment: I don't know, just observed this.

Comment: I found the `Test` class inheriting from those private classes being legal in the C++11 standard (see 11.3), but could not find anything specific explicitly excluding this for template classes. Provided I did not oversee it, I do not see any reason why there should be a difference with template classes, so I conclude clang is correct and gcc errs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a workaround for this odd issue...

Create a struct with a nested struct that inherits the inner structs :

```
template <class... Types>
struct BaseInherit {
  struct Inner : public Types::Inner... {};
};
```

Then, inherit from BaseInherit's nested inner in Base :

```
template <class... Types>
class Base : public BaseInherit <Types...>::Inner {};
```

This is what I had to do for GCC (6.3.1).

Edit: Forgot to say that you would then add BaseInherit as the friend struct, and not Base. Example :

```
class S1 {

  template <class... Types>
  friend struct BaseInherit;

  struct Inner { int member1, member2; };

};
```

Edit : How the workaround was found - I was trying to figure out the order in which the compiler would deduce variadic templates when inheriting. Since it complained when they were directly inherited, I thought that it may work in the scope of the class. Of course, we can't inherit from its own nested struct, so we put it in another struct / public class's nested struct.

Comment: I will check this. But the class named "Inner" is not private in the code given by you. For me it is my requirement.

Comment: @PremkumarU Why should the Inner class be private? Your own template class inherits publicly, too, from those private inner classes...

Comment: @ben Your workaround works. I am really wondering how you find this workaround. I am happy to accept this as my answer and award bounty. But if possible could you please explain how do you found this workaround? Thank you

Comment: @Aconcagua I want that inner struct to be part of the class template and at the same time that inner struct need not to be accessed away from my library. That is why I make it private and be accessible from the class template because of friend declaration. Is there any other alternative design which is better than my approach?

Comment: @PremkumarU I'm not too sure what else you could do if you'd like to directly inherit. I noticed you inherited publicly from Base, so I assumed this would work for your example. Another way to hide BaseInherit as an implementation detail would be to put it in an anonymous namespace. I'll also update the answer to explain how I worked it out.

Comment: An alternative could have been letting an inner (proxy) class of the template class inherit the private member classes. This would have worked fine with GCC, too, for the cost of having to access the inherited members via `object.proxy.memberN`.